# Bonus marks award according to class and Int

Tags: python

I want to find a bonus mark for students who fail. If the student from room 1 fail less than 5 subjects he get 5 marks, if the student rom room 2 fail less than 4 subjects he gets 4 marks for each subject and if a student from class 3 fail less than 3 subjects, he gets 3 marks for each subject. If the students fails more, then they wont get any bonus marks. I expected the output to be 1. Bonus that the students  get (if they dont get any bonus then it should display no bonus mark awarded) 2. The total number of bonus mark obtained.

When I did no bonus mark awarded, it gave me no output.

```
def main():
    room = int(input('Class: '))
    failed = int(input('Subjects failed: '))


    bonus = 0.0

    if (room == 1 and failed <= 5):
        bonus = (5 * failed)
        perbonus = 5
    elif (room == 2 and failed <= 4):
        bonus = (failed * 4)
        perbonus = 4
    elif (room == 3 and failed <= 3):
        bonus = (failed * 3)
        perbonus = 3
    else:
        print("Your bonus: ",perbonus)
        print("Total bonus",bonus)

main()
```

```
Class: 2
Subjects failed: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You only print in the `else` clause, which means you'll only ever print anything if `bonus` and `perbonus` are never calculated.  Just get rid of the `else`.

Comment: i got rid of it, but it still gave me the same output

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the changes to your else block. That the only problem I see

Comment: You will need to outdent the code that was in the else, or it will remain in the scope of the last elif

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def main():
    room = int(input('Class: '))
    failed = int(input('Subjects failed: '))


    bonus = 0.0

    if (room == 1 and failed <= 5):
        bonus = (5 * failed)
        perbonus = 5
    elif (room == 2 and failed <= 4):
        bonus = (failed * 4)
        perbonus = 4
    elif (room == 3 and failed <= 3):
        bonus = (failed * 3)
        perbonus = 3

    print("Your bonus: ",perbonus)
    print("Total bonus",bonus)

main()
```

You else statemnt is preventig to print anything if contition happens, and you only always get bonus= 0.0 and perbouns does not exit if condition doesnt happen. Just remove else

Comment: What do you mean by bonus=0.0 and perbouns does not exit?

Comment: if condition dont happen this func will retunr error: perbonus referenced before assignment

Comment: Oh, okay. then just fix it. add try.. except or something

Comment: You can just do an if statement:
if room > 3 or failed > 5:
         print ("wrong imput, try it again")

Comment: Yes, or you can just do an else: (like my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have your output in the scope of an 'else' clause.

Try removing the else and outdent the print lines to remove them from the scope of the last 'elif' clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have else: to your code. if your code reaches your if or elif, it will never go to the else: statement, so your results won't print.
So, do lilke this:

```
def main():
    room = int(input('Class: '))
    failed = int(input('Subjects failed: '))

    
    bonus = 0.0

    if (room == 1 and failed <= 5):
        bonus = (5 * failed)
        perbonus = 5
    elif (room == 2 and failed <= 4):
        bonus = (failed * 4)
        perbonus = 4
    elif (room == 3 and failed <= 3):
        bonus = (failed * 3)
        perbonus = 3
    else: # add it to prevent error
        bounus = 0
        perbonus = 0
    print("Your bonus: ",perbonus) # remove the else: and unindent this
    print("Total bonus",bonus) # unindent this

main()
```